# TTL gate characteristics

Tags: bjt, ttl

In case of BJT for example, the input characteristics can be described with \$I_B=f(V_{BE})\$ and output characteristics with \$I_C=f(V_{CE})\$.
How can the input and output characteristics be described in case of TTL gates?

Comment: \$I_C\$ is a function of both \$V_{CE}\$ and \$I_B\$ in a BJT. More than just \$V_{CE}\$ alone.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

You may model a TTL gate, at least the original low-power devices as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO4IbJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>